# Errors in FXM Log

Tags: sitecore-commerce, fxm

I am attempting to use FXM with Sitecore 9.1.1 to federate a few renderings into another website (following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zNnA08qgpc8). I have configured everything on the Sitecore side, and the FXM editor shows my renderings in the external website appropriately.  I have deployed the beacon and published my changes in Sitecore.

On the external website, I can see the beacon being pulled in but I do not see the renderings replacing my selectors.  The selector is a very simple #id selector.

When checking the network activity, I see a 500 error on the external website: http://mysite.com/sitecore/api/ssc/Beacon/Service/beacon/trackPageVisit/?contactId=&sessionId=&page=http%3A%2F%2Fproportal.mysite.com%2F&referrer=&rt=1567782189215

In the FXM logs on my sitecore website, I see this error:

```
35100 17:03:09 ERROR [FXM Tracking] [Error] : [TrackPageVisit] : Page = http://proportal.mysite.com/ : Referrer =  : CID = 
Exception: System.ArgumentNullException
Message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: Current
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String argumentName)
   at Sitecore.FXM.Pipelines.Tracking.TrackPageVisit.TrackPageVisitProcessor.Process(ITrackPageVisitArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.FXM.Tracking.TrackingManager.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<TrackPageVisit>b__0(FxmRequestContext fxmContext, TrackingResult result)
   at Sitecore.FXM.Tracking.TrackingManager.GenericServeTrackingRequest(SpoofedHttpRequestBase spoofedRequest, String contactId, Action`2 implementation)
   at Sitecore.FXM.Service.Controllers.BeaconController.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<TrackPageVisit>b__0()
   at Sitecore.FXM.Service.Controllers.BeaconController.ExecuteTrackingRequest(String requestInfo, Func`1 implementation)
```

There's also another error in my primary log (I am unsure if this is related):

```
21684 17:07:26 ERROR Exception when executing agent aggregation/pathAnalyzerLiveAgent
Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XdbModelConflictException
Message: One or more local models conflict with the xDB service layer.
 'RegisterConnectEventModel, 0.1' does not have a remote version
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.Initialize(XmlNode configNode)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient(String clientConfigPath)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.XConnect.DefaultXdbContextFactory.CreateReadOnly()
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.Agents.TreeAggregatorAgent.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()
38284 17:07:28 ERROR Exception when executing agent aggregation/aggregator
Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XdbModelConflictException
Message: One or more local models conflict with the xDB service layer.
 'RegisterConnectEventModel, 0.1' does not have a remote version
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.Initialize(XmlNode configNode)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient(String clientConfigPath)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.XConnect.DefaultXdbContextFactory.CreateReadOnly()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.AsyncPoolScheduler`2..ctor(IAsyncProcessingPool`1 pool, IXdbContextFactory xdbContextFactory, ExpandOptions options, Int16 maxBatchSize, BaseLog log)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.InteractionAggregationAgent.<ExecuteCoreAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.Agent.<ExecuteAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.AsyncBackgroundService.<ExecuteAgentAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.AsyncBackgroundService.<RunAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
```

Any clues as to what may be misconfigured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed in your solution RegisterConnectModelEvent is missing.

**RegisterConnectModelEvent**  is a Sitecore Commerce model for xConnect .

Copy the file c:\inetpub\wwwroot\\XConnectModels\Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.XConnect.Models.json and Paste it to two locations to overwrite:
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\.xconnect\App_data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_data\Models
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\.xconnect\App_data\Models

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution is outlined here: https://github.com/raseniero/Sitecore-v901-XP1-Scaled-Installation/issues/3

xConnect models were not lining up.  After resolving this, FXM began working!